# Magento 2: How to move category description to main column

Tags: magento2, category, xml, category-description

How can I move the category description from top of the page into main column of the category page just above product list toolbar?

I guess it should be doable by extending the `catalog_category_view.xml` in

> app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout

but for some reason I can't manage to do that with move element tag.

I have this in my

> app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>  
      <move element="category.description" destination="category.products" />
  </body>
</page>
```

And this in my

> app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('category.description'); ?>
<?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
   <?php echo $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what move element tag are you using?

Comment: <move element="category.description" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="product_list_toolbar" />

Comment: do you have anything else in the catalog_category_view.xml? do you have multiple versions of the xml file?

Comment: No, nothing else there. I don't think that I have multiple versions of it. Where could another version be?

Comment: you might have a version in Magento_Catalog and a version in Magento_Theme

Comment: Did not spot any additional xml's that seems to have any effect on this. Well, I ended up hiding the extra title and description with CSS on category page. Not that pretty, but working...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I did it this way:

```
<move element="category.description" destination="category.image" />
```

And then inside:

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/category/image.phtml
```

Called:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('category.description'); ?>
```

Because I wanted it inside the image, but you could put it just below instead.

I'm sure there's a better way but can't check atm.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but still not working. Updated my question.

Comment: @Webninja - Try getBlockHtml instead of getChildHtml. Technically it shouldn't make a difference as it is a child anyway but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Ben - That did the trick! It did not move the description, but it printed it again. Now description appears two times in different locations of the page. Have to remove other one somehow.

Comment: For some reason anything I put here: app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml has no effect. Tried to remove the description completely with this: <referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true" />

Comment: Hmmm if that works it sounds like the block isn't actually a child of `category.products`. Let me see if my Magento 2 box is booting properly, if so I'll put up an answer an example for you.

Comment: No luck sorry, damned Magento 2 not supporting downgrading has screwed up my box :(

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code in `app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` file:

```
<move element="category.description" destination="content" before="-" />
```

Comment: hi dipesh, can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/329971/57334