# M2.3 - How to set Catalog -> Categories -> Content -> Description cms block based on shop by attributes selection programmatically?

Tags: attributes, magento2.3.4, dynamic, category-description

I want to set the category description cms block based on the shop by attributes selection on product listing page,

[image]

Comment: According to the information displayed, your overview can be found in Admin panel> Catalog> Categories> Mattress> Content> Description

Comment: Yes right, i need to change my description dynamically based on shop by attributes selection, eg. if customer select red color my description like showing information about red color, i hope you understand my point.

Comment: Are you on Enterprise (Commerce)? If so, there's a customer segmentation module that will allow you to do this.

Comment: Yes, i have an enterprise, can you pls explain in more.

Comment: Is that possible to use the customer segmentation module to change the category description cms block programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.description">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/category/description.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/description.phtml**

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ActiveFilter');
$filterLabel = 'my_'.$blockObj->getActiveFilter();
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
    ->setBlockId($filterLabel)
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

**Vendor/Module/Block/ActiveFilter.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Class ActiveFilter
 * @package Vendor\Module\Block
 */
class ActiveFilter extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Resolver
     */
    protected $layerResolver;

    /**
     * ActiveFilter constructor.
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getActiveFilter()
    {
        $layer = $this->layerResolver->get();
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        $filterLabel = "";
        foreach ($activeFilters as $filter) {
            $filterLabel = $filter->getLabel();
            $filterValue = $filter->getValue();
        }
        return $filterLabel;
    }
}
```

And Also remove **catalog_product_collection_load_after** event..

Comment: Where i can remove this catalog_product_collection_load_after

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119115/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod

Comment: Finally where i can add condition like if this attribute active or selected show this cms block?

Comment: If apple attribute selected i need to set cms block : mattress_plp_attribute_king, if orange attribute selected i need to show : mattress_plp_attribute_queen, how to set like this?

Comment: change condition in description.phtml file based on your requirement

Comment: Small condition:  My default cms block not showing, i mean if no one attribute selected display my default cms block which is assigned from admin panel https://snipboard.io/MJFTcN.jpg

Comment: Now, without any condition my description section empty.

Comment: you can copy magento default file and add custom condition for this

Comment: Can you pls explain more bro, I can't get.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/description.phtml this file is disaply category description so you can copy this file in your module and add custom logic as per your requirement

Comment: I am using custom theme, so that this file I am already declared in app/design/frontend/vendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog can I do condition here?

Comment: yes you can add condition on this file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119119/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: yes............

Comment: I just paste the code into app\design\frontend\Zero\Mytheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\category\description.phtml copy from vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/description.phtml

Comment: yes and add your logic

Comment: https://justpaste.it/9lo8s can you pls help for that. My logic if no attributes selected show default one.

Comment: can you please explain you logic ??

Comment: If no attribute selected, show my selected cms block https://justpaste.it/9lo8s

Comment: This one : https://snipboard.io/MJFTcN.jpg

Comment: I hope you understand my point,

Comment: Any help rathod, still getting confusion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119127/discussion-on-answer-by-rk-rathod-m2-3-how-to-set-catalog-categories-con).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your block class name for this description section is `Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` and  name in Layout is `category.description`,

Create a **View model** class that checks the current  page has  filters

### View Model Class

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\MagentoModule\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class CategoryDescription implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
     */
    private $layerResolver;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function  hasFilterList()
    {
        $listOfFilter = [];
        $filters = $this->layerResolver->get()->getState()->getFilters();
        if (!is_array($filters)) {
            $filters = [];
        }

        foreach ($filters as $item) {
            $listOfFilter[$item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()] =
            $this->request->getQueryValue($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar());
        }
        return $listOfFilter;
    }
}
```

### Called view model class for catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

Create `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml` or add the below code at `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.description" template="StackExchange_MagentoModule::category/description.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="description_view" xsi:type="object">StackExchange\MagentoModule\ViewModel\CategoryDescription</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: May i know path for catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

Answer (score 0):

That would be outside of the existing Magento functionality.

You could write a few generic descriptions that could apply to which ever attribute. Something like "Here at StackOverflow we love coders that use %1" and then have a knockout observer listening to the filter selection (you'd need to look into the filtering js to know what that is handled by)

That way you could append to the standard category description and be like `<my_description> + renderSelectedAttributeMessage()`.

My point being you would have to roll your own solution for this as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Can you pls explain in brief?

Comment: Looks like this might be an enterprise solution. Good luck!

Comment: Can you pls explain how to exactly achieve? new to commerce edition.

Comment: I personally have never used commerce edition. So unfortunately you're probably left with the only option of contacting your support team through Magento... If there is one? I'm not too sure