# How to check PLP page layered navigation attributes selected or not using Observer?

Tags: attributes, event-observer, magento2.3.4

I am using event ( **catalog_product_collection_load_before** )for check PLP page layered navigation attributes selected or not, my observer,

app\code\Zero\DescBlock\Observer\Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Zero\DescBlock\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Data implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;
    
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param LayerResolver $layerResolver,
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayerResolver $layerResolver,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        
        // Get selected filters
        $layer         = $this->catalogLayer;
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        
        // checking variable activeFilters using log
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');  
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();  
        $logger->addWriter($writer);  
        $logger->info('Your log details: ' .$activeFilters); 

    }
}
```

Log not return anything.

Any help thanks?

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply please check answer and let me know if any query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this :-

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- event catalog_product_collection_load_after -->
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="rk_rathod_product_available"
                  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CollectionObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CollectionObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Class CollectionObserver
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer
 */
class CollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
     */
    protected $layerResolver;

    /**
     * CollectionObserver constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     */
    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layer = $this->layerResolver->get();
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        foreach ($activeFilters as $filter)
        {
           $filterLabel = $filter->getLabel();
           $filterValue = $filter->getValue();
           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');  
           $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();  
           $logger->addWriter($writer);  
           $logger->info('Filter Label: ' .$filterLabel); 
           $logger->info('Filter Value: ' .$filterValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still custom.log not generated.

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, really thank you.

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Comment: Actually i am doing this task for my another task, like if one attribute selected the relevant cms block set to the category description. can you pls help me this also https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/329971/57334

Comment: Before that is it possible?

Comment: i m not sure...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/329971/57334 in this quation you want to disaply custom text based on filter ??

Comment: Not custom text, as you know we can set cms block for category description, i need to set programatically.

Comment: eg. if customer select attribute color red, i need to set category description cms block  like id :10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119081/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119081/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod

Comment: Now my log display Filter Label, is possible can we add add condition to this like if Filter Label is "apple" set category description cms block (cms block id : 10)

Comment: I hope you understand my point, right?

Comment: Hi rathod, any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339482/57334